# Does `wipefs` require --force to erase the partition table on a disk?

Tags: filesystems, partition-table

The `wipefs` man page says that:

> `-f, --force`
> Force erasure, even if the filesystem is mounted.  **This is required in order to erase a partition-table signature on a block device**.

So this means that every time I want to overwrite a partition table signature on a block device, I need to add `-f`.

Later in the man page, one of the usage examples given is:

> `wipefs --all --backup /dev/sdb`
> **Erases all signatures** from the device /dev/sdb and creates a signature backup file `~/wipefs-sdb-<offset>.bak` for each signature.

So this example overwrites all signatures from a block device, obviously including the partition table signature. According to what was stated earlier, this will not work, because it does not include `-f`.

Now I don't know whether to use `-f` or not. When trying to erase **all** signatures from a disk, including the partition table, is the `--force` option required?

Comment: What is the question? Consider reporting the issue to wipefs maintainers, this is a questions and answers site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that the wording of the man page seems unclear or misleading. The last paragraph of text before the options states:

> Note that by default wipefs does not erase nested partition tables on non-whole
> disk devices. For this the option --force is required.

Here, they're talking about non-whole disk devices, which is worded differently than the text under the `-f` option, which you have included.

### --force is neither required nor sufficient to erase 'all' partition data

Given that it's unclear, I have done some testing of wiping partition table data using the following scheme:

1. Create MBR partition table on device (flash drive)
2. Create a single partition
3. Put a vfat filesystem on the partition, and give the filesystem a label.
4. Erase the partition table data using `wipefs` with various arguments
5. Examine the results: this includes the output from `wipefs` during its operation, the output of `lsblk` for the device, and the results of opening the device in `cfdisk`. Further, after using `cfdisk` to re-create an identical partition table and partition on the device, observe whether the recreated partition gets the old label.

Conclusions:

1. With this simple partition scheme, and with the partition unmounted, the force option has no effect on the data that gets erased when running `wipefs` on the device (not the partition). That is, whether running `wipefs -a /dev/sdX` or `wipefs -af /dev/sdX`, the partition table is wiped from the device. But upon recreating the partition table in `cfdisk`, the old label is found and applied to the new partition. So the partition table was wiped, but the data for the partition itself was not. The output of `wipefs` during its operation is consistent with this.
2. To actually delete **all** the partitions' data as well as the partition table of the device, all partitions must be listed explicitly, before listing the device. The man page gives a hint about this in the example within the text of the third paragraph (I have changed their sdc to sdX, to prevent any accidents during copy/paste into a terminal):

   ```
   wipefs -a /dev/sdX1 /dev/sdX2 /dev/sdX
   ```

   Or, letting the shell fill in the values with a wildcard expression:

   ```
   wipefs -a /dev/sdX? /dev/sdX
   ```

   This successfully deletes all the partition data from the device, as well as the partition table itself.